# What's the error in this bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

I have the syntax error: end of file not expected printed out when I execute this bash script and I don't understand why, does anyone have a reason?

```
 #!bin/bash
COUNTER=$1
while [  $COUNTER -ne $2 ]; do
    echo "$COUNTER " >> pcascript.out
    COUNTER2=0
    SUMA=0
    while [ $COUNTER2 -lt 5 ]; do      
         elt=/usr/bin/time -f="%e" ./pi.pg $COUNTER
         SUMA=$SUMA+$elt
         COUNTER2=$COUNTER2+1
    done
    MEDIA=$SUMA/5
    echo " " >> pcascript.out
    echo MEDIA >> pcascript.out
    let COUNTER=$COUNTER+500
done
```

Comment: I'd suspect it has to do with the line `elt=/usr/bin/time -f="%e" ./pi.pg $COUNTER`. Are you trying to get the output of this line?

Comment: yes, I'm trying to get the output of that command (time measuring when executing the pi.pg program with a parameter...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some comments:

- there is a typo in the shebang:

  ```
  #!bin/bash
  ```
- `-ne` means not equal so the loop can easily become infinite if `$1 + n*500 != $2`. Also missing `$1`, `$2` are not being handled consistently:

  ```
  COUNTER=$1
  while [  $COUNTER -ne $2 ]; do
  ```
- you don't need to redirect each `echo` output one by one:

  ```
   echo "$COUNTER " >> pcascript.out
  ```
- `$elt` assigned to literal command, not its output. `-f="%e"` option produces a number prefixed by `=`; `time` prints to stderr:

  ```
   elt=/usr/bin/time -f="%e" ./pi.pg $COUNTER
  ```
- `bash` doesn't support floating point arithmetic, but `$elt` can be float; magic number `5` used several times:

  ```
       SUMA=$SUMA+$elt
       # ...
  MEDIA=$SUMA/5
  ```
- you forgot `$` before `MEDIA` and you don't need to redirect each `echo` output one by one:

  ```
  echo " " >> pcascript.out
  echo MEDIA >> pcascript.out
  ```

Here's a script that tries to fix enumerated above problems:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Find average time it takes to run ./pi.pg $i over several repetitions
set -e
# for i in [$1..$2)
i=${1:?}
while [ $i -lt ${2:?} ]; do
    total=0
    j=0
    while [ $j -lt 5 ]; do
        t=$(/usr/bin/time -f'%e' ./pi.pg $i 2>&1 >/dev/null)
        total=$(echo "$total + $t" | bc)
        j=$(($j + 1))
    done
    mean=$(echo "scale=2; $total / $j" | bc)
    echo "$i $mean"
    i=$(($i + 500))
done >>pcascript.out
# or you could redirect the whole script ./measure-time >>pcascript.out instead
```

Comment: Another alternative for redirecting the output is: exec >> pcascript.out

Comment: @William Pursell: +1 if you need to redirect stdout of the whole script and fix the destination then `exec >> pcascript.out` works.

Answer (score 3):

The line:

```
elt=/usr/bin/time -f="%e" ./pi.pg $COUNTER
```

should be:

```
elt=$(/usr/bin/time -f="%e" ./pi.pg $COUNTER)
```

This is command substitution.

[Edit] Math also needs to be substituted:

```
SUMA=$(($SUMA + $elt))
COUNTER2=$(($COUNTER2 + 1))
```

Otherwise, COUNTER2 will end up looking like

```
1+1+1
```

as putting things next to eachother like that in Bash is effectively string concatenation.

Comment: The SUMA and COUNTER2 lines also need substitution:
SUMA=$(($SUMA + $elt))

Comment: @DavidSouther Indeed, thanks for catching that too.  A `let` would also have worked to do the math, analogous to the script's last line.

Comment: `time` writes it's output to stderr, you'll additionally need to redirect to stdout for this to work and drop output of `pi.pg` (if there is any) `elt=$(/usr/bin/time -f="%e" ./pi.pg $COUNTER 2>&1 >/dev/null)`. Moreover `pi.pg` must not write anything to stderr.

Comment: Thanks to all of you! I'll try all these changes now!